# I always get "Unresolved reference" on imports. Ktor

Tags: kotlin, import, ktor

so I'm having problems when trying to manually use new (some specific) imports.

I am trying to send a Http request in with Ktor/Kotlin. But I cant seem to get some one of the imports to work. I hit this wall over and over again. "Unresolved reference: ".

My progress is like this: (for example want to use the function `"val client = HttpClient(CIO)"`

1: Get the import at the top

`import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*`
"

2: Notice i get "Unresolved reference: cio" so i add the ktor-client-cio dependency in "build.gradle.kts"

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
```

3: Try to rebuild. Doesent work. Get stuck.

I have time problem every time i want to manuly set up a new plugin and have to create a new prodject with the plugin pre set up.

Any help on what step i am missing?

(if any mention of the instalation block is mentioned i add stuff there aswell, it looks like this atm

```
fun Application.module() {
configureSecurity()
configureHTTP()
configureMonitoring()
configureSerialization()
configureDatabases()
configureRouting()}
```

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA do you use?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman 2021.2.3

Comment: Can you try to use the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA?